# Problema no Css ou no JavaScript que só funciona no Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá estou fazer um controle onde há 2 tabelas a tabela **A** e **B** , pois então.
Essa tabela **B** só aparece se eu clicar no **botao B** , e a tabela A "some".
Entre tanto isso acontece certinho no FireFox , porem no Edge e no chrome não, o erro e que não da para clicar no botão. 
Esse efeito de "sumir a div" foi feito via Java script usando um display: none no css. o codigo esta aqui nesse link tambem

https://jsfiddle.net/Larck6/c1peqhvL/32/

```js
var diva;
var divb;



window.onload = function(){
  
  diva = document.getElementById("diva");
  divb = document.getElementById("divb");
  
  var bta = document.getElementById("bta");
  bt1.onclick = mostrarDiv1;
  var btb = document.getElementById("btb");
  bt2.onclick = mostrarDiv2;
  
  diva.classList.add ("escondido");
  divb.classList.add ("escondido");
  
  
}

function mostrarDiv1(){
  
  diva.classList.remove("escondido");
  divb.classList.add("escondido");
     
}

function mostrarDiv2(){
  diva.classList.add("escondido");
  divb.classList.remove("escondido");

}
```

```css
/* Fonts from Google Fonts - more at https://fonts.google.com */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700');

body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #444;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  color-adjust: exact;
  color-adjust: [exact];

}

h1 {
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font: 10pt "Tahoma";
}

@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}

page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}




.container{

  margin-left: auto; /* magin externa Esquerda */ 
  margin-right: auto; /* magin externa direita */
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  padding-left: 15pt;
  padding-right: 15pt;
}


.fundo{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../img/Fundo_simples_A4.jpg");
  color-adjust: exact;
  z-index:-1;

}


/*img e cabecalho*/
.cabecalho{
  width:100%;
  z-index:1;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 5pt;
  /* position: absolute;teste*/
}

/* FIM cabecalho*/

/* logo RCm*/
.logo{
  height:auto;
  width:20%;
  float: left;
}

.logo img{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;

}
/*FIM logo RCM*/

.escondido{
  display:none;

}


.botao{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index:100;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 80%;
}

#bt1{
  height:30px;
  width:60px;
  text-align:center; 
  color:#000000;
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.12);
}


button{
  height:30px;
  width:60px;
  text-align:center; 
  color:#000000;
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.12);
  
}

#button{
  height:30px;
  width:60px;
  text-align:center; 
  color:#000000;
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.12);

}




/*Titulo central*/
.titulo{
  height:auto;
  width:50%;
  float: left;
  color: #c40027;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 10pt;
}
/* FIM Titulo  central*/

/*Simbolo vermelhor*/
.logo2{
  height:auto;
  width:20%;
  float: right;
  z-index:2;

}

.logo2 img{
  height:auto;
  width:40%;
  margin-left:40%;
  float: right;
}


/* fim simbolo vermelhor*/





.pratileira{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:15%;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;


}



.parte1{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;

}


.andar{
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 0;

}
.andar_p{
  height:70px;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.partileiraandar{
  width:10%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10pt;

}
.abc_dados_prateleiras{
  width:85%;
  float: left;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.p_l{
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;




}
.dados_pratileira_1{
  width:85%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;

}

#A01,#A02,#A03,#A04,#A05,#A06,#A07,#A08{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
}



/* >>>>>>>>Andar 1 <<<<<<<*/


#A11,#A12,#A13,#A14,#A15,#A16,#A17,#A18{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}




/* >>>>>Andadr 2<<<<<<<*/

#A21,#A22,#A23,#A24,#A25,#A26,#A27,#A28{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}


/*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Andar 3<<<<<<<<<<*/


#A31,#A32,#A33,#A34,#A35,#A36,#A37,#A38{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}



/* >>>>>>>>>>>> ******** TABELA B******** <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

#B01,#B02,#B03,#B04,#B05,#B06,#B07,#B08{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
}



/* >>>>>>>>Andar 1 <<<<<<<*/


#B11,#B12,#B13,#B14,#B15,#B16,#B17,#B18{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}




/* >>>>>Andadr 2<<<<<<<*/

#B21,#B22,#B23,#B24,#B25,#B26,#B27,#B28{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}



/*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Andar 3<<<<<<<<<<*/


#B31,#B32,#B33,#B34,#B35,#B36,#B37,#B38{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}





/* >>>>>>>>>>>> ||||||||| FIM TABELA B|||||||| <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Estoque</title>
        <script src="scripts/cssdiv.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
      </head>
<body>

        <div class="container">

          <div class="fundo">

            <div class="cabecalho">

              <div class="logo"><img src=""/></div>
              <div class="titulo">ESTOQUE BOBINAS</div>
              <div class="logo2"> <img src=""></div>

            </div>
            <!-- >>>>>>>>> botao <<<<<<<<< -->
            <div class="botao">
              <button id="bt1"> A </button>
              <button id="bt2"> B </button>
            
            </div>
            <!-- >>>>>>> FIM botao <<<<< -->


            

            <div id="diva"> <!-- >>>> INIcio da DIVA do botao 1 <<<<  -->
                          
             <!-- <div class="pratileira" onload="setTimeout('Atualizar()',1000)"><h3>Prateileira A</h3></div> -->
             <div class="pratileira"><h3>Prateileira A</h3></div>

              <div class="parte1">

                <div class="partileiraandar"> 

                  <div class="andar">Andares</div>
                  <div class="andar_p">Andar 0</div>
                  <div class="andar_p">Andar 1</div>
                  <div class="andar_p">Andar 2</div>
                  <div class="andar_p">Andar 3</div>

                </div>
                <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->
                <div class="abc_dados_prateleiras">
                  <div class="p_l">1</div>
                  <div class="p_l">2</div>
                  <div class="p_l">3</div>
                  <div class="p_l">4</div>
                  <div class="p_l">5</div>
                  <div class="p_l">6</div>
                  <div class="p_l">7</div>
                  <div class="p_l">8</div>
                </div> 
                <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->


                <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> inicio dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->
                <div class="dados_pratileira_1">
                  <?php
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A01");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A01"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A02");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A02"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A03");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A03"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A04");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A04"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A05");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A05"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A06");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A06"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A07");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A07"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A08");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A08"><?=$bobina?></div>



                  <!-- andar 1 -->
                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A11");
                  ?>

                  <div id="A11"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A12");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A12"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A13");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A13"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A14");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A14"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A15");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A15"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A16");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A16"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A17");
                  ?>
                  <div id="A17"><?=$bobina?></div>


                   <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A18");
                  ?> 
                  <div id="A18"><?=$bobina?></div>




                  <!-- andar 2 --> 

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A21");
                  ?>   
                  <div id="A21"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A22");
                  ?> 
                  <div id="A22"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A23");
                  ?> 
                  <div id="A23"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A24");
                  ?> 
                  <div id="A24"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A25");
                  ?> 
                  <div id="A25"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A26");
                  ?> 
                  <div id="A26"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A27");
                  ?> 
                  <div id="A27"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A28");
                  ?> 
                  <div id="A28"><?=$bobina?></div>




                  <!-- andar 3 -->

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A31");
                  ?>

                  <div id="A31"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A32");
                  ?>

                  <div id="A32"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A33");
                  ?>

                  <div id="A33"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A34");
                  ?>

                  <div id="A34"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A35");
                  ?>

                  <div id="A35"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A36");
                  ?>

                  <div id="A36"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A37");
                  ?>

                  <div id="A37"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("A38");
                  ?>

                  <div id="A38"><?=$bobina?></div>




                  <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> FIM dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->

                </div> 

              </div> 

              <!-- >>>> FIM Tabela completa A <<<<  -->
              

            </div> <!-- >>>> FIM da DIVA do botao 1 <<<<  -->



            <div id="divb"> <!-- >>>> INCIO da DIVB do botao 2 <<<<  -->
              
              
              <div class="pratileira"><h3>Prateileira B</h3></div>

              <div class="parte1">

                <div class="partileiraandar"> 

                  <div class="andar">Andares</div>
                  <div class="andar_p">Andar 0</div>
                  <div class="andar_p">Andar 1</div>
                  <div class="andar_p">Andar 2</div>
                  <div class="andar_p">Andar 3</div>

                </div>
                <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->
                <div class="abc_dados_prateleiras">
                  <div class="p_l">1</div>
                  <div class="p_l">2</div>
                  <div class="p_l">3</div>
                  <div class="p_l">4</div>
                  <div class="p_l">5</div>
                  <div class="p_l">6</div>
                  <div class="p_l">7</div>
                  <div class="p_l">8</div>
                </div> 
                <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->


                <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> inicio dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->
                <div class="dados_pratileira_1">


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B01");
                  ?>
                  <div id="B01"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B02");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B02"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B03");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B03"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B04");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B04"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B05");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B05"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B06");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B06"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B07");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B07"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B08");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B08"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <!-- andar 1 -->

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B11");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B11"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B12");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B12"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B13");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B13"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B14");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B14"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B15");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B15"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B16");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B16"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B17");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B17"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B18");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B18"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <!-- andar 2 --> 

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B21");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B21"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B22");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B22"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B23");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B23"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B24");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B24"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B25");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B25"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B26");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B26"><?=$bobina?></div>

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B27");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B27"><?=$bobina?></div>



                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B28");
                  ?>


                  <div id="B28"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <!-- andar 3 -->

                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B31");
                  ?>
                  <div id="B31"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B32");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B32"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B33");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B33"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B34");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B34"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B35");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B35"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B36");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B36"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B37");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B37"><?=$bobina?></div>


                  <?php  
                  $bobina = busca_endereco("B38");
                  ?>

                  <div id="B38"><?=$bobina?></div>





                  <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> FIM dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->

                </div> 

              </div> 

              <!-- >>>> FIM Tabela completa B <<<<  -->
              </div> <!-- >>>> FIM da DIV B do botao 2 <<<<  -->
              
              </div> <!-- FIm Fundo site -->
        </div> <!-- Fim container site -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem mais de um problema nesse código. Primeiramente que ele não deveria estar funcionando nem mesmo no Firefox, ao menos não da maneira que você postou, pois no seu HTML você declara `diva` e `divb`, mas no seu JavaScript você está buscando elementos com os ids `div1` e `div2`.

Depois nas funções `mostrarDiv1` e `mostrarDiv2`, ao invés de adicionar a classe `escondido` para um elemento e remover para o outro, você está adicionando e removendo a classe no mesmo elemento `div1`

Agora, quanto ao código estar se comportando de maneira diferente em cada navegador, é provavelmente devido a forma cada navegador carrega a página. No seu código, você declara uma função para ser disparada quando o `window` terminar de carregar, ou seja no `onload`, mas se o `window` já estiver carregado quando seu navegador interpretar o JavaScript, essa função nunca irá disparar.

Você deveria fazer algo do tipo:

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") onload();
else window.onload = onload;

function onload(){

  div1 = document.getElementById("diva");
  div2 = document.getElementById("divb");

  // ...

}
```

Dessa forma se o HTML já estiver carregado, você dispara a função, e se ele não estiver carregado, você coloca a função para ser disparada assim que ele carregar.

Comment: eu arrumei os erro foi na hora de resumir ele e colar aqui :D , mas agora esta correto , tentei fazer o if mas ainda nao rolou :(

Comment: Tem certeza que o erro não está na lógica do seu código? [Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/1kapeLbu/) está funcionando .

Comment: achei o erro era a div q fazia o background msm eu declarando o zindex -1 ou qualquer outro valor para ficar a baixo nao sei o motivo certo o navegador nao estava interpretando isso, foi so eu tirar o posição Z que deu certo vlw pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Não deveria funcionar em nenhum navegador, pois existem erros no código, como por exemplo nessas linhas:

```
div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
```

Não existe nenhum elemento com os id's `#div1` e `#div2`. Parece que você queria se referir às divs `#diva` e `#divb`. Neste caso, basta trocar os id's das divs das tabelas para `id="div1"` e `id="div2"`.

Outro problema é nas funções que mostram as tabelas, onde você deveria adicionar a classe `.escondido` em uma div e remover da outra e vice-versa, de acordo com o botão clicado, e você está fazendo isso apenas na `div1`, por exemplo:

```
div1.classList.remove("escondido");
div1.classList.add("escondido");
```

Teria que ser assim, na primeira função, por exemplo:

```
div1.classList.remove("escondido"); // mostra uma
div2.classList.add("escondido");    // e esconde a outra
```

Então, seu código deveria ser assim:

```js
var div1;
var div2;

window.onload = function(){
  
  div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
  div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
  
  var bt1 = document.getElementById("bt1");
  bt1.onclick = mostrarDiv1;
  var bt2 = document.getElementById("bt2");
  bt2.onclick = mostrarDiv2;
  
  div1.classList.add ("escondido");
  div2.classList.add ("escondido");
  
  
}

function mostrarDiv1(){
  
  div1.classList.remove("escondido");
  div2.classList.add("escondido");
     
}

function mostrarDiv2(){
  div1.classList.add("escondido");
  div2.classList.remove("escondido");

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #444;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  color-adjust: exact;
  color-adjust: [exact];

}

h1 {
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font: 10pt "Tahoma";
}

@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}

page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}




.container{

  margin-left: auto; /* magin externa Esquerda */ 
  margin-right: auto; /* magin externa direita */
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  padding-left: 15pt;
  padding-right: 15pt;
}


.fundo{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../img/Fundo_simples_A4.jpg");
  color-adjust: exact;
  z-index:-1;

}


/*img e cabecalho*/
.cabecalho{
  width:100%;
  z-index:1;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 5pt;
  /* position: absolute;teste*/
}

/* FIM cabecalho*/

/* logo RCm*/
.logo{
  height:auto;
  width:20%;
  float: left;
}

.logo img{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;

}
/*FIM logo RCM*/

.escondido{
  display:none;

}


.botao{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index:100;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 80%;
}

#bt1{
  height:30px;
  width:60px;
  text-align:center; 
  color:#000000;
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.12);
}


button{
  height:30px;
  width:60px;
  text-align:center; 
  color:#000000;
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.12);
  
}

#button{
  height:30px;
  width:60px;
  text-align:center; 
  color:#000000;
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.12);

}




/*Titulo central*/
.titulo{
  height:auto;
  width:50%;
  float: left;
  color: #c40027;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 10pt;
}
/* FIM Titulo  central*/

/*Simbolo vermelhor*/
.logo2{
  height:auto;
  width:20%;
  float: right;
  z-index:2;

}

.logo2 img{
  height:auto;
  width:40%;
  margin-left:40%;
  float: right;
}


/* fim simbolo vermelhor*/





.pratileira{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:15%;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;


}



.parte1{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;

}


.andar{
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 0;

}
.andar_p{
  height:70px;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.partileiraandar{
  width:10%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10pt;

}
.abc_dados_prateleiras{
  width:85%;
  float: left;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.p_l{
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;




}
.dados_pratileira_1{
  width:85%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;

}

#A01,#A02,#A03,#A04,#A05,#A06,#A07,#A08{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
}



/* >>>>>>>>Andar 1 <<<<<<<*/


#A11,#A12,#A13,#A14,#A15,#A16,#A17,#A18{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}




/* >>>>>Andadr 2<<<<<<<*/

#A21,#A22,#A23,#A24,#A25,#A26,#A27,#A28{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}


/*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Andar 3<<<<<<<<<<*/


#A31,#A32,#A33,#A34,#A35,#A36,#A37,#A38{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}



/* >>>>>>>>>>>> ******** TABELA B******** <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

#B01,#B02,#B03,#B04,#B05,#B06,#B07,#B08{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
}



/* >>>>>>>>Andar 1 <<<<<<<*/


#B11,#B12,#B13,#B14,#B15,#B16,#B17,#B18{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}




/* >>>>>Andadr 2<<<<<<<*/

#B21,#B22,#B23,#B24,#B25,#B26,#B27,#B28{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}



/*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Andar 3<<<<<<<<<<*/


#B31,#B32,#B33,#B34,#B35,#B36,#B37,#B38{
  height:70px;
  width:12%;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  color: #464545;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow:    9px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.77);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

 <div class="fundo">

   <div class="cabecalho">

     <div class="logo"><img src=""/></div>
     <div class="titulo">ESTOQUE BOBINAS</div>
     <div class="logo2"> <img src=""></div>

   </div>
   <!-- >>>>>>>>> botao <<<<<<<<< -->
   <div class="botao">
     <button id="bt1"> A </button>
     <button id="bt2"> B </button>
   
   </div>
   <!-- >>>>>>> FIM botao <<<<< -->


   

   <div id="div1"> <!-- >>>> INIcio da DIVA do botao 1 <<<<  -->
                 
    <!-- <div class="pratileira" onload="setTimeout('Atualizar()',1000)"><h3>Prateileira A</h3></div> -->
    <div class="pratileira"><h3>Prateileira A</h3></div>

     <div class="parte1">

       <div class="partileiraandar"> 

         <div class="andar">Andares</div>
         <div class="andar_p">Andar 0</div>
         <div class="andar_p">Andar 1</div>
         <div class="andar_p">Andar 2</div>
         <div class="andar_p">Andar 3</div>

       </div>
       <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->
       <div class="abc_dados_prateleiras">
         <div class="p_l">1</div>
         <div class="p_l">2</div>
         <div class="p_l">3</div>
         <div class="p_l">4</div>
         <div class="p_l">5</div>
         <div class="p_l">6</div>
         <div class="p_l">7</div>
         <div class="p_l">8</div>
       </div> 
       <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->


       <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> inicio dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->
       <div class="dados_pratileira_1">
         <?php
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A01");
         ?>
         <div id="A01"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A02");
         ?>
         <div id="A02"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A03");
         ?>
         <div id="A03"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A04");
         ?>
         <div id="A04"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A05");
         ?>
         <div id="A05"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A06");
         ?>
         <div id="A06"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A07");
         ?>
         <div id="A07"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A08");
         ?>
         <div id="A08"><?=$bobina?></div>



         <!-- andar 1 -->
         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A11");
         ?>

         <div id="A11"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A12");
         ?>
         <div id="A12"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A13");
         ?>
         <div id="A13"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A14");
         ?>
         <div id="A14"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A15");
         ?>
         <div id="A15"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A16");
         ?>
         <div id="A16"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  

         $bobina = busca_endereco("A17");
         ?>
         <div id="A17"><?=$bobina?></div>


          <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A18");
         ?> 
         <div id="A18"><?=$bobina?></div>




         <!-- andar 2 --> 

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A21");
         ?>   
         <div id="A21"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A22");
         ?> 
         <div id="A22"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A23");
         ?> 
         <div id="A23"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A24");
         ?> 
         <div id="A24"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A25");
         ?> 
         <div id="A25"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A26");
         ?> 
         <div id="A26"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A27");
         ?> 
         <div id="A27"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A28");
         ?> 
         <div id="A28"><?=$bobina?></div>




         <!-- andar 3 -->

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A31");
         ?>

         <div id="A31"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A32");
         ?>

         <div id="A32"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A33");
         ?>

         <div id="A33"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A34");
         ?>

         <div id="A34"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A35");
         ?>

         <div id="A35"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A36");
         ?>

         <div id="A36"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A37");
         ?>

         <div id="A37"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("A38");
         ?>

         <div id="A38"><?=$bobina?></div>




         <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> FIM dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->

       </div> 

     </div> 

     <!-- >>>> FIM Tabela completa A <<<<  -->
     

   </div> <!-- >>>> FIM da DIVA do botao 1 <<<<  -->



   <div id="div2"> <!-- >>>> INCIO da DIVB do botao 2 <<<<  -->
     
     
     <div class="pratileira"><h3>Prateileira B</h3></div>

     <div class="parte1">

       <div class="partileiraandar"> 

         <div class="andar">Andares</div>
         <div class="andar_p">Andar 0</div>
         <div class="andar_p">Andar 1</div>
         <div class="andar_p">Andar 2</div>
         <div class="andar_p">Andar 3</div>

       </div>
       <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->
       <div class="abc_dados_prateleiras">
         <div class="p_l">1</div>
         <div class="p_l">2</div>
         <div class="p_l">3</div>
         <div class="p_l">4</div>
         <div class="p_l">5</div>
         <div class="p_l">6</div>
         <div class="p_l">7</div>
         <div class="p_l">8</div>
       </div> 
       <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->


       <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> inicio dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->
       <div class="dados_pratileira_1">


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B01");
         ?>
         <div id="B01"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B02");
         ?>

         <div id="B02"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B03");
         ?>

         <div id="B03"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B04");
         ?>

         <div id="B04"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B05");
         ?>

         <div id="B05"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B06");
         ?>

         <div id="B06"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B07");
         ?>

         <div id="B07"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B08");
         ?>

         <div id="B08"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <!-- andar 1 -->

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B11");
         ?>

         <div id="B11"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B12");
         ?>

         <div id="B12"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B13");
         ?>

         <div id="B13"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B14");
         ?>

         <div id="B14"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B15");
         ?>

         <div id="B15"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B16");
         ?>

         <div id="B16"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B17");
         ?>

         <div id="B17"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B18");
         ?>

         <div id="B18"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <!-- andar 2 --> 

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B21");
         ?>

         <div id="B21"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B22");
         ?>

         <div id="B22"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B23");
         ?>

         <div id="B23"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B24");
         ?>

         <div id="B24"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B25");
         ?>

         <div id="B25"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B26");
         ?>

         <div id="B26"><?=$bobina?></div>

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B27");
         ?>

         <div id="B27"><?=$bobina?></div>



         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B28");
         ?>


         <div id="B28"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <!-- andar 3 -->

         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B31");
         ?>
         <div id="B31"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B32");
         ?>

         <div id="B32"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B33");
         ?>

         <div id="B33"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B34");
         ?>

         <div id="B34"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B35");
         ?>

         <div id="B35"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B36");
         ?>

         <div id="B36"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B37");
         ?>

         <div id="B37"><?=$bobina?></div>


         <?php  
         $bobina = busca_endereco("B38");
         ?>

         <div id="B38"><?=$bobina?></div>





         <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> FIM dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->

       </div> 

     </div> 

     <!-- >>>> FIM Tabela completa B <<<<  -->
     </div> <!-- >>>> FIM da DIV B do botao 2 <<<<  -->
     
     </div> <!-- FIm Fundo site -->
</div> <!-- Fim container site -->
```

Comment: o erro que vc acusou eu ja havia arrumado, foi na hora de resumir para o forum  que errei, entretanto o erro de nao funcinar no chrome e no firefox ainda correr :(

Comment: Eu uso o Chrome e está funcionando certinho aqui, inclusive o exemplo funcional que coloquei na resposta. Acredito que o problema então deva ser outra coisa.

Comment: achei o erro, era a div q fazia o background msm eu declarando o zindex -1 ou qualquer outro valor para ficar a baixo. nao sei o motivo certo o navegador nao estava interpretando isso, foi so eu tirar o posição Z que deu certo vlw pela ajuda